# how long is the FB postId expiration date?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-3.0

I write an android application which does a FB like to a FB post.

I succeed in doing it, but after a long time I get this `response`:

```
{
  Response:  responseCode: 400, 
  graphObject: null, 
  error: 
        {
         HttpStatus: 400, 
         errorCode: 100, 
         errorType: OAuthException, 
         errorMessage: (#100) Error finding the requested story
        },
 isFromCache:false
}
```

for the code:

```
Request request = new Request(
        session,
        takeFromPublicMacrosOrServer(currentOffer.postId)
                + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // Request complete
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    UnlockRequestToServer unlockRequestToServer = new UnlockRequestToServer(
                            mOffersListActivity,
                            PublicMacros.TYPE_UNLOCK_FB_LIKE,
                            currentOffer.postId);

                } else {
                    final String errorMsg = "error: "
                            + response.getError()
                                    .toString();
                    Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, errorMsg);
                    if (BaseApplication
                            .getCurrentActivity() != null) {
                        BaseApplication
                                .getCurrentActivity()
                                .runOnUiThread(
                                        new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                if (PublicMacros.DEBUG) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            BaseApplication
                                                                    .getCurrentActivity(),
                                                            errorMsg,
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                            .show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                    }
                }
                String re = response.toString();
            }
        });
request.executeAsync();
```

Does someone know how long is postId valid for FB like action ?

Comment: are you  able to access other things using same post_id?

Comment: Does the 'like' get registered on the post in question before AND after the message?

Comment: In my application I have checked the Session.getActiveSession.getstate().isopen which returns true or false and in case of false i try to get the active session and post the pic or status.

Comment: I renew the session but i save an oldPostId to which I want to do a "like". so when is it too old I get exception: FB cannot find this postId. The q is how long is this time?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I get a page Access Token that does not expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706228/how-do-i-get-a-page-access-token-that-does-not-expire) May contain some useful iformaion for you.

[Facebook 3.0 How to post wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725316/facebook-3-0-how-to-post-wall?rq=1) Shows you how to post to your wall

This Question shows you the 'like' [Facebook like in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454659/facebook-like-in-android) using android.

**EDIT**

> Facebook doesn't notify you that a previously issued access token has
>   become invalid. Unless you have persisted the **expiry** time passed to
>   your App along with the access token, your app may only learn that a
>   given token has become invalid is when you attempt to make a request
>   to the API. Also, in response to certain events that are
>   security-related, access tokens may be invalidated before the expected
>   expiration time.

Comment: please help me with the exact question. I was asking about expiration time. You have posted many links from FB doc, but didn't answered my question

Comment: this post explains a LOT to do with your question: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#errors